# Getting token but not scope inside that token using MSAL code

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-ad-msal, msal

I’m replacing AAD code to MSAL.

Login page first hit Startup.cs

Here I'm generating token using user info if generated token I checked with jwt encoder it shows scope.

Startup.cs

```
var graphApiResource ="https://graph.microsoft.com/";
IConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(this.Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:ClientId"])
.WithRedirectUri(x.Properties.Items[OpenIdConnectDefaults.RedirectUriForCodePropertiesKey])
.WithClientSecret(this.Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:ClientSecret"])
.WithAuthority(this.Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:AADInstance"] + this.Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:TenantId"])
.Build();

var scopes = new string[] { $"{graphApiResource}/.default" };

AuthenticationResult authenticationResult;
authenticationResult = await app.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(scopes, x.ProtocolMessage.Code).ExecuteAsync();
var token = authenticationResult.AccessToken;
```

This works perfectly fine.
After this startup.cs code ran from userinfo.cs which is generating token but as I'm not passing any user details while generating token token generated do not have scope inside it and unable to use it successfully.

UserInfo.cs

```
var graphApiResource ="https://graph.microsoft.com/";
IConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(this.configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:ClientId"])
            .WithRedirectUri($"{this.httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext.Request.Scheme}://{this.httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext.Request.Host}{this.configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:CallbackPath"]}")
            .WithClientSecret(this.configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:ClientSecret"])
            .WithAuthority(this.configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:AADInstance"] + this.configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:TenantId"])
            .Build();

var scopes = new string[] { $"{graphApiResource}/.default" };

AuthenticationResult authenticationResult;
authenticationResult = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
var token = authenticationResult.AccessToken;
```

What should be done?

Permission details:

[image]

My issue is previously I'm using old nuget i.e Microsoft. IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory

Code was this -

```
private async Task<string> GetAuthorizationHeaderCore(string resource)
{
    var objectId = (this.httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier"))?.Value;
    var userTenantId = (this.httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid"))?.Value;

    var distributedTokenCache = new DistributedTokenCache(
        this.scopedCacheFactory,
        this.dataProtectionProvider,
        this.telemetryClient,
        userTenantId + ":" + objectId
    );

    var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(this.authOptions.ClientId, this.authOptions.ClientSecret);
    var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(this.authOptions.AADInstance + this.authOptions.TenantId, distributedTokenCache);

    AuthenticationResult authenticationResult;

    var accessToken = await GetTokenWithFallBackAsync(this.httpContextAccessor.HttpContext, "access_token");
    if (accessToken != null)
    {
        if (this.httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext?.Items?["isAuthenticatedService"] as bool? == true)
        {
            authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, this.backgroundServiceClientCredential).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        else
        {
            var userPrincipalName = this.httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
            var userAssertion = new UserAssertion(accessToken, "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer", userPrincipalName);
            authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCredential, userAssertion).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Just hope we already have a token (openid case)
        var userIdentifier = new UserIdentifier(objectId, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId);
        authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(resource, clientCredential, userIdentifier);
    }

    return authenticationResult.CreateAuthorizationHeader();
}
```

Now I want to use msal nuget i.e Microsoft.Identity.Client so want to convert above code which can work for new nuget.

Comment: Could you please include `API permissions` snip of your application from Portal?

Comment: Updating question with permission details

Comment: Note that, tokens generated with **delegated** flows like authorization code flow, interactive flow, etc... have `scp` claim with Delegated permissions as those flows involve user interaction.

Comment: In your UserInfo.cs, you're using `AcquireTokenForClient` which is meant for client credentials flow that generates a token for the client application itself, not for a user. You need to grant permissions of `Application` type while using client credentials flow that are visible in `roles` claim of decoded token.

Comment: How to achieved it pls help me with steps or code sample thanks in advanced

Comment: @halfer posted a new question pls check and help thank you 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77578455/getting-issue-with-msal-code-while-generate-token

Comment: If you're still stuck on this, perhaps you could (a) explain in the comments on the answer below how that solution does not work for you, and (b) offer a bounty on the question to get more people to see it.

Answer (score 1):

> Note that, you need to grant permissions of **Application** type while using client credentials flow that are visible in  `roles`  claim of decoded token.

I registered one Azure AD application and granted **`API permissions`** of **Application** type as below:

[image]

Now, I generated **access token** using client credentials flow with your code as below:

```cs
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;

var graphApiResource = "https://graph.microsoft.com/";
IConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create("appID")
            .WithClientSecret("secret")
            .WithAuthority("https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/authorize")
            .Build();

var scopes = new string[] { $"{graphApiResource}/.default" };

AuthenticationResult authenticationResult;
authenticationResult = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
var token = authenticationResult.AccessToken;
Console.WriteLine($"Access Token: {token}\n");
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I decoded this token in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms) website where it has **`roles`** claim with **Application** permissions as below:

[image]

You can now use this token to fetch **user info** of any user in that tenant like this:

```cs
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string accessToken = await GetAccessToken();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
        {
            await GetUserDetails(accessToken, "user_id_here"); // Replace "user_id_here" with the actual user ID
        }
    }

    static async Task<string> GetAccessToken()
    {
        string clientId = "appId";
        string clientSecret = "secret";
        string tenantId = "tenantId";

        var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(clientId)
            .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
            .WithAuthority(new Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}"))
            .Build();

        var scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

        var result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
        return result.AccessToken;
    }

    static async Task GetUserDetails(string accessToken, string userId)
    {
        var graphApiEndpoint = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}";

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

            var jsonResponse = await client.GetStringAsync(graphApiEndpoint);

            Console.WriteLine("User Details:");
            Console.WriteLine(jsonResponse);
        }
    }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

If your use case is to fetch **signed-in** user details, you must use **delegated** flows like authorization code flow, interactive flow, etc... for generating access token that involves user interaction, by granting **Delegated** permissions.

Comment: Thank you got it but how to do it for user i mean how to pass user details? Anyway of that??or can we pass values from startup.cs to userinfo.cs?

Comment: Check the updated code that includes both token generation and fetching user information.

Comment: Yes usecase is that only to get user details kindly give me your inputs on that pls

Comment: Gor it thanks alot but what should we do with that use info ahead? Im bit confused

Comment: Are you trying to fetch **signed-in user** details or any particular user details?

Comment: Signed in user only so goal is in azure AD keep it user delegate and like startup.cs token working it should work in userinfo.cs

Comment: In Startup.cs, you used delegated flow like authorization code(delegated) flow to generate token. You can directly utilize that token in `UserInfo.cs` for getting signed-in user details.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256065/discussion-between-sridevi-and-neo).

Comment: I have update actual issue in question