# Getting issue with MSAL code while generate token

Tags: c#, .net, azure-ad-msal

My issue is previously I'm using old nuget i.e Microsoft. IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.

Code was this UserInfo.cs -

```
private async Task<string> GetAuthorizationHeaderCore(string resource)
{
    var objectId = (this.httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier"))?.Value;
    var userTenantId = (this.httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid"))?.Value;

    var distributedTokenCache = new DistributedTokenCache(
        this.scopedCacheFactory,
        this.dataProtectionProvider,
        this.telemetryClient,
        userTenantId + ":" + objectId
    );

    var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(this.authOptions.ClientId, this.authOptions.ClientSecret);
    var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(this.authOptions.AADInstance + this.authOptions.TenantId, distributedTokenCache);

    AuthenticationResult authenticationResult;

    var accessToken = await GetTokenWithFallBackAsync(this.httpContextAccessor.HttpContext, "access_token");
    if (accessToken != null)
    {
        if (this.httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext?.Items?["isAuthenticatedService"] as bool? == true)
        {
            authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, this.backgroundServiceClientCredential).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        else
        {
            var userPrincipalName = this.httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
            var userAssertion = new UserAssertion(accessToken, "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer", userPrincipalName);
            authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCredential, userAssertion).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Just hope we already have a token (openid case)
        var userIdentifier = new UserIdentifier(objectId, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId);
        authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(resource, clientCredential, userIdentifier);
    }

    return authenticationResult.CreateAuthorizationHeader();
}
```

I'm trying `new MSAL Microsoft.Identity.Client nuget` below code is generating token but do not have scope and continually hitting login page.

```
IConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(this.Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:ClientId"])
              .WithRedirectUri(x.Properties.Items[OpenIdConnectDefaults.RedirectUriForCodePropertiesKey])
              .WithClientSecret(this.Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:ClientSecret"])
                  .WithAuthority(this.Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:AADInstance"] + this.Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:TenantId"])
                  .Build();

 var scopes = new string[] { $"{graphApiResource}/.default" };

 AuthenticationResult authenticationResult;
 
 authenticationResult = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
```

Comment: Exact duplicate of your prior question: [How to convert my code from ola AAD to MSAL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77570100/how-to-convert-my-code-from-ola-aad-to-msal) Please do not deliberately duplicate your questions. You can cast a reopen vote on your old one if you feel it is now on-topic (I am not sure it is).

Comment: At 15k reputation, I wonder if I would expect your questions to be of better quality generally Neo. They always need repair work (they seem to always be authored on a mobile phone, and are written as if Stack Overflow is a chat-room). Questions are generally kept permanently here, so a spell-checker is recommended. And, obviously, readers expect a decent prior effort to solve the problem.

Comment: Boilerplate advice: _Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened_.

Comment: It looks like you have a [third question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77552241/getting-token-but-not-scope-inside-that-token-using-msal-code) on this topic. It may be best to let this one close and persist with that one.

Comment: I got you ! I tried multiple code but its not working for me :( one code i have added in question here.